# Calculating the `length` of `permutations xs`

Tags: math, functional-programming

In Haskell's GHCi, type in `length$ permutations [1..8]` and it's instant. With `length$ permutations [1..16]` you're looking at .. minutes, hours perhaps? If all we want is the actual number of results that `permutations xs` *would* produce (ie. not needing to run through them) there obviously must be a simple cheap formula knowing just the `length` of `xs`.

I'm regrettably slow with maths, but given `len = length xs`, I noticed that the answer is found by giving any positive `len` to:

```
numofperms 0 = 0
numofperms 1 = 1
numofperms ln = ln * (numofperms (ln - 1))
```

But while this is obviously faster than evaluating all the `permutations`, why recurse! I'm sure there's a 'formula' hiding in there that I just can't immediately/intuitively see. How would one go about translating the above logic into a simple non-recursing mathematical calculation? "Something with factorials" or some such?

**Before you mark as duplicate:** I'm sure I can easily find "the answer to which formula gives the number of permutations" readily here or elsewere, but the **real question** (if permitted on this format) is how does one jump from intuitively written recursive logic to cheaper and correct calculations  as in `(x * (x+-foo ^ bar))` --- this can surely become an educational thread in this respect for other budding functional programmers arriving here in the future!

Comment: Not "Something *with* factorials" --- just a factorial itself. Also -- `length$ permutations [1..16]` would probably crash Haskell with a memory error.

Comment: "how does one jump from intuitively written recursive logic to cheaper and correct calculations as in `(x * (x+-foo ^ bar))`" – math, and it’s not always intuitive. There are a few common things to try for simple cases, but in general, uh… you just have to solve it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression?

Comment: @JohnColeman: `length` doesn’t hold on to past results, so Haskell would just take a long time to evaluate it.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture, for example, where the really simple function may or may not have a closed form of `f(n) = 1`. Nobody’s solved it yet.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks. Its been a while since I did anything with Haskell. I thought I remembered `$` as forcing eager evaluation. I see now that I was confusing it with `$!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one isn’t correct:

```
numofperms 0 = 0
```

The number of permutations of 0 elements is 1 (`permutations [] == [[]]`). With that in mind, maybe it would help to make things shorter:

```
f(0) = 1
f(n) = n * f(n - 1)
```

Look familiar? It’s n! – the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).